# dmath inside dgroup writes over equation number

Tags: equations, breqn

The following gives an output where the second eqaution writes over the equation number

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a +a+a+a+ b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+a+a+a
 \end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}

\end{document}
```

Using just

```
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a +a+a+a+ b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+a+a+a
 \end{dmath}
```

without the `dgroup` environment leads to correct output.

It looks like this ((1a) and (1.b) are in the `dgroup` environment whereas (2) is not):
[image]

Did I make a mistake or is this a bug?
What is the correct way to handle this situation?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is but `breqn` is quite unfinished so I wouldn't use it if I was you. Neither Michael Downes (before he passsed away) or Morten Høgholm (before we left the LaTeX community) got `breqn` fully working.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Thx for the comment. Is there any better alternative for automatic line breaks (with brackets)?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139669/looking-for-a-smarter-left-right/140005#140005

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thx for the hint.As far as i understand it does your option not provied automatic breaking (which would be one of my main motivations to use breqn).

Comment: @ungerade You are correct.  The referenced page does not provide automatic breaking, one must use some sort of tabbing arrangement.  However, what it does provide is a possible approach to the "with brackets" part of your comment.  That is, it offers the possibility of preserving bracket height  when breaking a term across two lines of an equation.

Answer (score 3):

The `bregn` package is alpha software and this unlikely to change.  See the package's documentation for a number of open issues.  So to answer your first question, yes this is a bug.

There are a number of internal variables you can adjust, either globally or internally in a given group, to work around your problem.  The most relevant choice seems to be

- `\eqnumsep` a dimension specifying the minimum space between the body and the equation number, default `10pt`

In your example `\eqnumsep=4em` resolves the problem causing the line to break by moving the equation number to the next line.  A larger value will cause the equation itself to break over two lines.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\verb+\eqnumsep=4em+
\begin{dgroup}\eqnumsep=4em
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a +a+a+a+ b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+a+a+a
 \end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}

\noindent
\verb+\eqnumsep=5em+
\begin{dgroup}\eqnumsep=5em
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a +a+a+a+ b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+a+a+a
 \end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}

\noindent
Default \verb+\eqnumsep+
\begin{dgroup}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
    a = a +a+a+a+ b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+b+a+a+a
 \end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}

\end{document}
```